# relational database in eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

hay i have table schema like this

table **transaction_fueler**

```
id | code | user_id |user_name| ref_code | area_name
```

table **user_community**

```
user_id | community_id
```

table **user_community** is pivot table from table **users** and **community**

in table **transaction_fueler** i want to get **community_id** from table **user_community**, depends on **user_id* in **transaction_fueler**  how to get **community_id** depends on **user_id** in table **transaction_fueler** ??

i stuck this.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i recommend  joining the two tables and select the columns you want:

```
  $values = DB::table('transaction_fueler')
            ->join('user_community', 'user_community.user_id', '=', 'transaction_fueler.user_id')
            ->select('transaction_fueler.*', 'user_community.community_id')->get();
```

Comment: where is $user_id ?

Comment: you want to select all transaction_fueler record with community_id?

Comment: yes,, but this is get all data,, not find($user_id)

Comment: ok, i misunderstand you , i removed that where, please try now